# How to enter key manually using R's cyphr library

Tags: r, encryption

Suppose I create a key using R's cyphr library

```
library("cyphr")

k <- sodium::keygen()
# > k
# [1] af ee af 08 5b 75 42 7b 83 05 67 69 82 66 55 67 ea ee 04 76 90 cb b2 19 49 11 15 ab 53 5f e9 aa

key <- cyphr::key_sodium(k)
key
# > key
# <cyphr_key: sodium>
```

This seems to work OK.

Now suppose I never store this key in a file anywhere, but write it down on a piece of paper. When it comes time to decrypt a file I manually enter the key like so to try to recreate the sodium cyphr key object:

```
k <- "af ee af 08 5b 75 42 7b 83 05 67 69 82 66 55 67 ea ee 04 76 90 cb b2 19 49 11 15 ab 53 5f e9 aa"
key <- cyphr::key_sodium(noquote(k))

# Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
# In addition: Warning message:
#   In file(con, "rb") :
#   cannot open file 'af ee af 08 5b 75 42 7b 83 05 67 69 82 66 55 67 ea ee 04 76 90 cb b2 19 49 11 15 ab 53 5f e9 aa': No such file or directory
```

Why doesn't this work? Can it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is split the string at the space with `strsplit`, loop over the `list` of values, convert to `raw` through `hexmode`

```
k <- unname(sapply(strsplit(k1, " ")[[1]], function(x) as.raw(as.hexmode(x))))
```

-checking

```
k
#[1] af ee af 08 5b 75 42 7b 83 05 67 69 82 66 55 67 ea ee 04 76 90 cb b2 19 49 11 15 ab 53 5f e9 aa
str(k)
#raw [1:32] af ee af 08 ...
```

-use as input

```
key <- key_sodium(k)
key    
#<cyphr_key: sodium>
```

---

Regarding why `noquote` didn't work, it is because it is still a `character` class overrided with `noquote` and not `raw`

```
str(noquote(k1))
# 'noquote' chr "af ee af 08 5b 75 42 7b 83 05 67 69 82 66 55 67 ea ee 04 76 90 cb b2 19 49 11 15 ab 53 5f e9 aa"

class(k)
#[1] "raw"
class(noquote(k1))
#[1] "noquote"
```

We need the `class` to be `raw`

#### data

```
k1 <-  "af ee af 08 5b 75 42 7b 83 05 67 69 82 66 55 67 ea ee 04 76 90 cb b2 19 49 11 15 ab 53 5f e9 aa"
```

Comment: That gives me: Error in sodium_load_key(key) : Unexpected length -- expected 32 bytes

Comment: @ixodid can you check now.  Sorry, there was a mistake in my judegement earlier